# Toggle bool with checkbox and playerprefs in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a checkbox in Unity UI that returns a bool endless game as 'true', and 'false' if it's a timed game. I want to do this with PlayerPrefs. I understand that PP only supports int, float and strings. I created a function that true to 1.

I have a Game Manager that handles the overall state of the game, this gameobject is the only one in my game that doesn't get destroyed on load.

So far the Game Manager has a bool 'endless' that is initialized as

```
endless = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Endless", 1) == 0;
```

in the start function.

Now I have an options menu that houses the checkbox, in this script is the following:

```
public void OnToggleEndless()
{
    if (endLessToggle.isOn)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Endless", manager.endless ? 1 : 0);
        
        print("Endless Button ticked");
    }
    else 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Endless", manager.endless ? 0 : 0);
        print("Endless Button unticked");            
    }
    
}
```

But when I hook it up, play the game and go to the options menu and tick 'Endless Game', nothing happens. I tried to put the OnToggleEndless(); method in Update, but that just gives me endless lines of the print("Endless Button ticked"); message, the PlayerPrefs aren't saved. I'm wondering if the checkbox is even hooked up properly. I cannot figure this one out!

Comment: " But when I hook it up, play the game and go to the options menu and tick 'Endless Game', nothing happens" Are you sure that you attached this "OnToggleEndless()
" function to ToggleButton event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The PlayerPrefs aren't saved

The saving of the `PlayerPrefs` seems faulty are you sure you want to actually check for `manager.endless` instead of `endLessToggle.isOn`.

Because the state of `endLessToggle.isOn` changes depending if you enabled or disabled the checkbox. But the state of `manager.endless` never changes and is set to either true/false at the start of the game.

This results in you not actually changing the `PlayerPrefs` variable when you toggle the checkbox.

**Example:**

```cs
private void Start() {
    // Check if we enabled or disabled the endlessToggle Checkbox last time we played
    // and set the checkbox accordingly.
    endLessToggle.isOn = (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Endless", 1) == 0);
}

// Call when we toggle the Checkbox.
public void OnToggleEndless() {
    // Get the current state of our toggle button.
    int enable = endLessToggle.isOn ? 1 : 0;
    // Log result into console to test it.
    Debug.Log("We set Endless to: " + enable);
    // Set the PlayerPrefs equal to our current state.
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Endless", enable);
}
```

I don't think you need to use a a global variable from your `GameManager` anyway, because you already have the `PlayerPrefs` which does the same thing for you.

Additionally you need to set the state of the CheckBox equal to the `PlayerPrefs` when you start the Game.

Comment: Thanks Mathew! I forgot to save the playerprefs! Also my options menu was screwed up somehow and I had to reassign the script to it. It works great now! Thanks again for taking the time to read and respond to my question!